# Retrieve data from JSON where list items have specific/known values using JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON file with block like below

```
  {
    "id": 0000,
    "sGName": "SG1",

    "customProperties": [
      {
        "id": 100000,
        "name": "clustersIP",
        "value": "ABC"
      }
    ],

    "filters": [
      {
        "id": 74616,
        "attributeName": "serverName",
        "value": "Sever101"
      },
      {
        "id": 74617,
        "attributeName": "bigIPPool",
        "value": "server101v1"
      }
    ],

  },
```

I am looking for JQ in bash to retrieve
sGName, where "attributeName"="serverName", and  "value"="Sever101" Can some one please help on that?

I might have multiple "sGName"

Comment: Note that while it might be pronounced Jason, it's written JSON, which is an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: Thanks for correction

Comment: BTW, please try to write titles that are specific enough to distinguish your specific question from all the other "how can I use jq to retrieve X?" questions. (If it's *not* distinguishable, then in theory, you should be able to use those other questions' answers and not need to ask a new one). I've tried to edit towards that end now.

Comment: Your sample input seems incomplete, and there is no desired output in your question

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the following command :

```
jq --raw-output 'map( select(.filters | any(.attributeName == "serverName" and .value == "Sever101")) |.sGName) | join("\n")'
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/UJiKKUvWQk).

With the serverName criteria extracted as a parameter :

```
jq --raw-output --arg serverName "Sever101" 'map( select(.filters | any(.attributeName == "serverName" and .value == $serverName)) |.sGName) | join("\n")'
```

[oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/) proposes a more streamlined solution :

```
jq --raw-output --arg serverName "Sever101" '.[] | select(any(.filters[]; .attributeName=="serverName" and .value==$serverName)).sGName'
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. Where are we passing the ServerName Value? My Jason file will have multiple server names so have to filter by its value

Comment: Replace `"serverName"` with `$s`, and adjust the call to `jq --arg s "serverName" ...`; likewise for `"Server101"`.

Comment: `map ... select ... length` could easily be replaced with `any`

Comment: @oguzismail thanks, I was sure I was missing something simpler but I didn't find what